# Unexpected results on groupby([]).sum()

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```py
n = df1.groupby(['Year', 'State', 'Regulator', 'Industry','Product', 'Count']).sum()     # <-- this produces the error
```

Problem description
[Hi, I think there's a problem dropping/excluding data points with groupby.sum function. I've performed the following code (see above), which at hindsight seemed ok until I compared with the same data using Excel and/or simple plot of the dataset. In addition, removing 'Count' will throw off values on other df columns. Thanks for checking this out.]

Expected Output

```
Year | 2012
State | Alabama
Regulator | SEC
Insurance/Annuity Products | 2
Stocks | 4

Year | 2012
State | Alabama
Regulator | FDIC
Debit Card | 1
Residential Mortgage | 3
```

Output of pd.df

```
Year | 2012
State | Alabama
Regulator | FDIC
Debit Card | 1
Residential Mortgage | 1
```

Comment: Please include also the error message (what error actually occurred).

Comment: There's no actual error message, the error is getting the wrong values. For example instead of getting Residential Mortgage = 3, after groupby and sum i get Residential Mortgage = 1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I've had ran the code including and excluding the Column ['Count'] from the code which gave me a mix of good and bad results. For some reason the CSV wasn't being read correctly if that makes any sense. Column ['Count'] was dtypes int, but it seems was being read as string. So i did a .apply(pd.to_numeric), removed 'Count' and re-ran the cell which solved the issue.

Here's the final code for groupby/sum:

```
n = df1.groupby(['Year', 'State', 'Regulator', 'Industry','Product'])['Count'].sum()
```